# How much gunpowder could the average Napoleonic ship of the line carry?

Tags: warfare, naval, napoleonic-wars, age-of-sail

I've run across a few references to a ship's magazine detonating during combat, and by all accounts the explosions were massive. I'm trying to put them into context a bit by figuring out how much gunpowder these ships had. The explosion of l'Orient in the battle of the Nile would be a fantastic example.

The only reference I could find was a story in a book called Astoria by Peter Stark, describing the [Tonquin incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonquin_(1807)) where, after a battle with the Tla-o-qui-aht tribe, five men were left alive aboard the ship. Four elected to abandon the ship aboard the longboat, while one remained aboard. He waited for the tribe to attempt to board the ship, then detonated the ship's magazine of 9,000 pounds of gunpowder.

This was a fairly small ship, though, with only ten cannon. How much could a ship-of-the-line such as l'Orient or the Victory carry in comparison?

Comment: I wouldn't call either l'Orient nor the Victory "average" ships of the line during the Napoleonic period. They were both 1st rates (100+ guns), whereas the average fleet vessel was a 74-gun ship.

Answer (score 17):

A quick search on the [HMS Victory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Victory) leads us to [militarynavalhistory.net](http://militarynavalhistory.net/shippictures/art_hms_victory_01.htm), where they have this to say concerning the armaments of the Victory:

> The armament comprised thirty 32-pound cannons in the lower gun deck,
>   twenty-eight 24-pound cannons on the middle gun deck, thirty 12-pound
>   cannons on the upper gun deck, twelve 12-pound cannons on the
>   quarterdeck and another two shooting forward on the forecastle. A
>   special addition was the two 68-pound carronades placed on the
>   forecastle, able to fire such huge projectiles at short range only.
>   The carronades were mounted on partially rotating carriages which
>   allowed to aim them either sidewards or frontally. The ship carried **35 tonnes of gunpowder** and 120 tonnes of ammunition to serve her large
>   artillery battery.

A [Tonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonne) is about 2,204.6 pounds, so  77,161 pounds of gunpowder on the Victory. (or 35,000 kg)

A similar figure can also be found in the publication:[HMS Victory Pocket Manual 1805: Admiral Nelson's Flagship At Trafalgar](https://books.google.com/books?id=SYxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=HMS%20Victory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsjISynerdAhUEn1MKHYoUAy8Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=powder&f=false)
By Peter Goodwin

> The Victory had three powder magazines: the grand magazine and two ready hanging magazines. The former, approximately 32
>   square feet in area and 10 feet high, consisted of three main
>   compartments creating an industrial assembly line. First was the
>   pallating flat, containing **35 tons of gunpowder** in 784 barrels, each
>   containing 100lb (45kg) of powder. If ignited, this amount of
>   gunpowder had the explosive equivalent of 47 tons of TNT.

For comparison, another [ship of the line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_the_line), the [French ship César (1768)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ship_C%C3%A9sar_(1768)), which was a 74-gun ship, (so a little more average then the *Victory*), had the following armaments:

> César carried twenty-eight 36-pounder guns on her lower deck, and
>   thirty 18-pounder guns on her upper deck. In addition, sixteen
>   8-pounder guns were distributed on the fore and aftcastle. In total
>   César's armament weighed around 215 tons. 6,000 cannonballs, weighing
>   some 67 tons, were carried. There was also around 8 tons of bar, chain
>   and grape shot. **20 tons of gunpowder** was embarked, stored in the form
>   of cartridges or in bulk in the depths of the ship. On average, each
>   gun had 50 to 60 cannonballs.

Comment: That makes it 31,751.46 kg for non-imperialists like me.

Comment: Thanks, I related the answer in pounds as that was the OPs units in the question.

Comment: What kind of ton is that? Not today's 1000 kg?

Comment: Well that's a great example of massive rounding errors. 35 tonnes a 1000kg (it even says so in the Wikipedia article) are 35000kg which roughly translate to “more than 70000 pounds“ which should then translate to “more than 31,751.46 kg“ when calculating 70000/2204.6, (which doesn't make sense at all). Or you don't go that way around and it's just 35 tonnes, which is already metric.

Comment: 1 tonne is 0.984 imperial tons so to a first approximation a metric tonne is the same as an old fashioned imperial ton.

Comment: I'm curious about the 35 tonnes figure, it equates to about 850 barrels (a powder barrel held 90 lbs) which is a lot higher than the 450~500 barrel capacity I've seen quoted for a 1st rate of the period (and the Victory was small for her type).

Comment: @Jos: Please don't use so many significant figures. 31751.46 kg is a very precise number for a very inaccurate estimate.

Comment: @Jos 35 tonnes is already metric .... why are you converting back?

Comment: Some of the confusion may come from the fact that there are at least 3 different types of ton. Long tons, short tons, and metric tons. Unless we are certain which ton is used in the original source, converting is confusing: and that's assuming the source here isn't itself confusing units from an earlier source

When the Victory was in service, the ton as used by the Royal Navy was 2240 lb or 1016 kg. Now, a ton can mean 2240 lb (1016 kg), 2000 lb (907 kg), or 1000kg (2204 lb) depending on context. Does anyone know which "ton" Peter Goodwin used in his book? I'd assume either long or metric

Comment: Lets not forget [tuns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tun_(unit)). Seriously, debating units and math is distracting, and comments are not meant for discussion...(Mods?)

Comment: Ibid. says `On a full burst on either side the artillery aboard the HMS Victory could deliver almost half a tonne of projectiles to a distance of about 2 kilometers, impulsed by 200 kilograms of gunpowder.`, so I guess it's already talking "metric tonnes".